# Is there a way to prevent the Terraform google_container_cluster from being destroyed and recreated when nothing changes?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I know there are similar issues on Github for the Terraform google provider, regarding the idempotency of google_container_cluster; however, none seem to match my simple example.  Any attempt to apply a Terraform plan wants to destroy and recreate my cluster, which is a 6+ minute operation.

There are no obvious changes to the cluster, but the terraform state suggests that the id of the cluster is the cluster's name, but that the new id is computed; thus, the cluster must be recreated.  Can I prevent this?

I am following the recommended example for setting up a cluster: defining a cluster with `remove_initial_node_pool=true` and `initial_node_count=1`, and then creating an explicit node pool as a dependent resource.  I have also tried creating a default cluster using the initial node pool. I am not specifying any additional attributes that others have associated with idempotency issue (such as master_ipv4_cidr_block).

Here is the basic Terraform setup.  I am using Terraform v0.11.13 and provider.google v2.6.0.

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "${var.google_project}"
  region      = "${var.google_region}"
  zone        = "${var.google_zone}"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  project                  = "${var.google_project}"
  name                     = "${var.cluster_name}"
  location                 = "${var.google_region}"

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    update = "15m"
    delete = "15m"
  }

}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "cluster_nodes" {
  name       = "${var.cluster_name}-node-pool"
  cluster    = "${google_container_cluster.cluster.name}"
  node_count = "${var.cluster_node_count}"

  node_config {
    preemptible  = "${var.preemptible}"
    disk_size_gb = "${var.disk_size_gb}"
    disk_type    = "${var.disk_type}"
    machine_type = "${var.machine_type}"
    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    ]
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    update = "15m"
    delete = "15m"
  }
}

output "cluster_ca_certificate" {
  value = "${google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate}"
}

output "host" {
  value = "${google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint}"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "${google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint}"
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

And so on.  Not shown are service account and cluster role binding to enable a Helm service account, and Helm release.  I don't think those matter here.

If I do `terraform apply` twice, the second invocation wants to destroy and create a new cluster.  Nothing's changed, so this shouldn't happen.
This would be OK, normally, except that I tend to see lots of timeouts from the terraform provider, and have to re-apply, which gets me nowhere, since reapplying causes the cluster to be destroyed and recreated.

Output from `terraform apply` looks like this:

```
terraform-gke$ terraform apply
data.template_file.gke_values: Refreshing state...
google_container_cluster.cluster: Refreshing state... (ID: test-eric)

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

-/+ google_container_cluster.cluster (new resource required)
      id:                                              "test-eric" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      additional_zones.#:                              "3" => <computed>
      addons_config.#:                                 "1" => <computed>
      cluster_autoscaling.#:                           "0" => <computed>
      cluster_ipv4_cidr:                               "10.20.0.0/14" => <computed>
      enable_binary_authorization:                     "" => <computed>
      enable_kubernetes_alpha:                         "false" => "false"
      enable_legacy_abac:                              "false" => "false"
      enable_tpu:                                      "" => <computed>
      endpoint:                                        "34.66.113.0" => <computed>
      initial_node_count:                              "1" => "1"
      instance_group_urls.#:                           "0" => <computed>
      ip_allocation_policy.#:                          "0" => <computed>
      location:                                        "us-central1" => "us-central1"
      logging_service:                                 "logging.googleapis.com" => <computed>
      master_auth.#:                                   "1" => "1"
      master_auth.0.client_certificate:                "" => <computed>
      master_auth.0.client_certificate_config.#:       "1" => "0" (forces new resource)
      master_auth.0.client_key:                        <sensitive> => <computed> (attribute changed)
```

Comment: You should probably explicitly set the `id` instead of having it computed if you want idempotence here.

Comment: `id` isn't a documented attribute for `google_container_cluster`.  Attempting to set it results in: `Error: google_container_cluster.i2kgke_cluster: : invalid or unknown key: id`.

Comment: Ok then yes: this sounds like a provider bug.

Answer (score 6):

So, ultimately, this is a provider bug, but it was caused by changes in the behavior of the kubernetes master service, between versions 1.11.x and 1.12.x, which Google rolled out just recently as the default for GKE nodes.  It's captured in the Terraform Google provider's Github issues as [#3369](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/3369).

The workaround is to tell Terraform to ignore changes in `master_auth` and `network`:

```
resource google_container_cluster cluster {
  master_auth {
    username = ""
    password = ""
  }
  # Workaround for issue 3369 (until provider version 3.0.0?)
  # This is necessary when using GKE node version 1.12.x or later.
  # It is possible to make GKE use node version 1.11.x as an
  # alternative workaround.
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ "master_auth", "network" ]
  }
}
```

*n.b.,* Perhaps to help others with the same problem... It's difficult to search places like the web and Github to find relevant answers to problems like this, because authors use many different terms to describe the sort of behavior that Terraform was exhibiting.  This issue is sometimes also described as a problem with Terraform idempotency and Terraform changes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are switched from basic (username/password) to TLS authorization as, according to your logs, you have new certificate generated and it forces new cluster.

Comment: I didn't think so.  I pass empty strings for username and password in master_auth, and according to Terraform's google provider documentation, "If this block is provided and both username and password are empty, basic authentication will be disabled."  My understanding was that GKE generates the certificate, which can be used to communicate with the Kubernetes master, but that doesn't explain why another Terraform apply would perforce need to generate a new cluster.

Comment: And, for what it's worth, I did just try setting GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON to point to a service account keyfile, successfully ran `terraform apply` in an empty state, and then ran it again.  It proposed to delete and recreate the cluster.